# Not Able to access getter of object returned from mocked method

Tags: spring, mockito

**TEST METHOD**

```
public void saveDemandCenterCategory() {
        String category = "testCategory";
        DemandCenterCategoryEntity demandCenterCategoryEntity = new DemandCenterCategoryEntity();
        demandCenterCategoryEntity.setId(1l);
        demandCenterCategoryEntity.setCategory(category);
        AgentEntity agentEntity = new AgentEntity();
        agentEntity.setId(11l);
        when(agentRepository.findByMobile(anyString())).thenReturn(agentEntity);
        when(demandCenterCategoryEntityRepository.save(any(DemandCenterCategoryEntity.class))).
                thenReturn(demandCenterCategoryEntity);
        assertEquals(demandCenterServiceImpl.saveDemandCenterCategory(anyString(),any()),isNotNull());
    }
```

Method to test

```
public DemandCenterCategoryEntity saveDemandCenterCategory(@NotEmpty String name,
                                                           @NotNull Entitlements entitlements) {
    DemandCenterCategoryEntity demandCenterCategoryEntity = new DemandCenterCategoryEntity();
    demandCenterCategoryEntity.setCategory(name);
    demandCenterCategoryEntity.setUpdatedBy(agentRepository.findByMobile(entitlements.getSubject()).getId());//null pointer
    return demandCenterCategoryEntityRepository.save(demandCenterCategoryEntity);
}
```

Getting Null pointer expression while getting data from mocked method returned data.

Comment: Where exactly you are getting `NPE`? Can you add stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the any() passed as entitlements argument that causes the NPE

By the way you should not use mockito matchers in the method under test